# How to get website name using httpwebresponse

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

In C#, I am using httpwebrequest to call a webpage and the websiteName is the url of the page i am trying to call.

```
            
            var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(websiteName);

            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException web)
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)web.Response;
            }
```

Everything is working fine. I am getting the response I want. The only problem is I want to get the title of the webpage. For example if I'm calling the URL"https://www.google.com/" I want the title of the page to show up as well. How do I do that?

Thank you for answering

Comment: [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) you'll need to parse the response to get it. [See this Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aQInf9) that utilizes the library...

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you ^^

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.